# snowpack woff2 font won't load

Tags: webpack, font-awesome, snowpack

snowpack super fast than webpack.
but I fetch some problem like when I import font-awesome my react project it fail.
cause snowpack won't load font (.woff2) file.

snowpack official website not about this topic.

**now how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now it's a pain. I'll explain why.

The theory:

1. [**Skip to the bottom if you don't use PostCSS**] Use Snowpack [`plugin-postcss`](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/plugins/plugin-postcss#readme) along with PostCSS [`postcss-import`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) plugin. Your PostCSS config could look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    // Other plugins...
  }
}
```

2. If you don't want to fix all `@font-face` paths, your CSS need to be in a subfolder like `css/app.css`, because Font Awesome CSS imports fonts fonts in a relative way (`../webfonts`).

```css
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';

/** Your CSS rules... **/
```

3. Last step, you should mirror the `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts` directory into the `webfonts` directory of your build destination (mine is `_dist`). This **could** be solved easily with the following code in your `snowpack.config.js`:

```json
"mount": {
  "node_modules/@fortawesome": {
    "url": "/webfonts",
    "static": true,
    "resolve": false
  }
}
```

But it won't work in production [because of this issue](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/issues/1286), basically Snowpack can't mirror anything from `node_modules` because this folder is hardcoded-excluded.

I found a workaround using the [`ncp package`](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) (`npm i --save-dev ncp`) and the [`@snowpack/plugin-run-script`](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/plugins/plugin-run-script#readme). Add the plugin to `snowpack.config.js` and set the `cmd` option to look like this:

```json
"plugins": [
  ["@snowpack/plugin-run-script", {
    "cmd": "ncp node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/ _dist/webfonts"
  }]
]
```

This will copy the Font Awesome `webfonts` folder contents into the web root folder named `webfonts`, so CSS relative imports will work.

**If you don't use PostCSS**, mount the folder at step 3 (will work in dev mode, not in production), use `ncp` as explained (will solve the issue in production) and add this line to your application JavaScript entry point:

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

Comment: installing @fortawesome/fontawesome-free is required for this to work AFAIK

Comment: Thanks for this extensive and helpful answer. Two additional hints for this particular use-case:
1. if you need globbing, try `copyfiles` instead of `ncp`:
`copyfiles -f node_modules/@fontsource/**/*.woff* public/files/`
2. since font assets rarely change, maybe add the copy task to the `package.json` and run only once: `scripts: { "copy-assets": "copyfiles -f node_modules/@fontsource/**/*.woff public/files/", "dev": "yarn copy-assets && snowpack dev", "build": "yarn copy-assets && snowpack build" }`